# Regex pattern to match numbers but also mixed numbers

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to be able to identify correctly integers but also mixed numbers (integers +  + a fraction).

So I'd like to match all of the below

```
48
34 1/2
34
46 2/3
42 1/2''
38 2/3"
24''
26"
```

What's the correct pattern to do so? I tried `/\d+ \d+\/\d+/` but that matches only the mixed numbers, leaving plain integers outside...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: Ideally, I'd like it to identify two single quotes, or a double quote at the end also... I updated the list!

Comment: `\d+(?: \d+\/\d+)?(?:''|")?` should do it.

Comment: This is a bit strange, isn't it?
https://i.ibb.co/GCywZwd/Screenshot-2021-07-07-173757.jpg

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/EcUCH8/1

Comment: I edited my comment so you're not using the latest regex

Comment: Yup, I didn't notice that you un-nested the two non-capturing groups! The latter definitely works like a charm! Thanks a million!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think you can consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's correct. Why not benefit from marking it as the correct answer...

Comment: Sorry for the commotion! Answer has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for you:

```regex
\d+(?: \d+\/\d+)?(?:''|")?
```

- `\d+` - capture one or more digits
- `(?: \d+\/\d+)?` - optionally capture a fraction preceded by a space
- `(?:''|")?` - optionally capture either two single quotes or a double quote

https://regex101.com/r/EcUCH8/1